# How do I draw a fitting bounding box around some text on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, typography

I am trying to draw some text with a box around it.

The best I could find is shown below.

1. It will work in almost no browsers
2. It doesn't exactly do what I want. I want the height of the boxes of the two examples to be the same. Otherwise either two such boxes or the text in them will not be aligned. (There is supposed to be a fontBoundingBoxAscent but that isn't enabled by default in any browser atm).

So, how do I do this?

If you have a solution that somehow draws a box and then puts the text in the middle with some baseline magic that is fine, too. I have not looked into that yet.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("#canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";

name = "Franky";
let x = 20;
let y = 20;

ctx.fillText(name, x, y);
var m = ctx.measureText(name)
ctx.strokeRect(x - m.actualBoundingBoxLeft, y - m.actualBoundingBoxAscent, m.actualBoundingBoxLeft + m.actualBoundingBoxRight, m.actualBoundingBoxAscent + m.actualBoundingBoxDescent);

name = "rowan";
x = 90;
ctx.fillText(name, x, y);

var m = ctx.measureText(name)
ctx.strokeRect(x - m.actualBoundingBoxLeft, y - m.actualBoundingBoxAscent, m.actualBoundingBoxLeft + m.actualBoundingBoxRight, m.actualBoundingBoxAscent + m.actualBoundingBoxDescent);
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=100 id="canvas"></canvas>
```